# background size changes depends on the number of menus

Tags: css, menu

How to make the background size changes depends on the number  of  menus. Is there any ways without using JavaScript, jQuery? I prefer without using JavaScript, jQuery but it is ok to use JavaScript, jQuery. Please see image below for description. Thank you!

http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/6076/17049838.png

Comment: Can you show the code and CSS of the menu? prefferably in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Having a container div with a float set

> float:left

and the child divs with a float set

> float:left

will make the container div automatically shrink/expand to the size of the child divs. Here's a fiddle showing this solution
http://jsfiddle.net/v9EVQ/

If this isn't working for you please show the code you are using for the menu.

EDIT:

if you do not want a width on col you can remove the width and the columns will automatically resize to the width of the content

http://jsfiddle.net/v9EVQ/3/

In the original example the col would contain each column of data, so the first col would have 
Action/Adventure, Children/Family, Comedy etc.
the second col would contain
Horror/Thriller, Factual, Music/Dance etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your example is setting the width for col so total width can keep. What I want is without setting col. Width can automatically change depends on the number of menu like http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/6076/17049838.png

Comment: You can remove the width on the col and it will resize to the content. http://jsfiddle.net/v9EVQ/1/